# console.log undefined in project netflix clone on react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm trying to make this Netflix Clone, I'm trying to use an API called TMDB to display movies and i can't understand why movies on console.log is undefined.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "../../axios"
import "./Row.css"

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow = false }) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setMovies(request.data.result);
            return request;
        }

        fetchData();
    }, [fetchUrl])
    console.log(movies)
    


    return (
        <div className='Row'>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

Comment: `request.data.result` is `undefined`

Comment: console.log the request and see what object you receive

Comment: could you provide the API URL if it is free?

Comment: try `request.data.data`, I think that will help :)